# How to extend a selection in the linux console editors nano and pico?

Tags: command-line-interface, gnu, linux

How do I extend a selection in nano and pico with the keyboard, so I can move and copy blocks?

Sorry, this is a question I would normally find out by myself but I have searched a lot in different occasions now without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this from inside the help screen in nano by pressing ctrl-g:

```
Ctrl    F-Key   Esc Key
^^      (F15)   (M-A)   Mark text at the cursor position  
M-^             (M-6)   Copy the current line and store it in the cutbuffer
^U      (F10)           Uncut from the cutbuffer into the current line
```

^ = ctrl
M = esc

So you position your cursor at the beginning of where you want to select and press `esc-a` or `ctrl-shift-6` or `F15` then move the cursor with the arrow keys to highlight the text. Once it is highlighted press `esc-6` to copy the text. Lastly move to where you want to paste and press `ctrl-u` or `F10`. I just tested this in nano 2.0.6 on OS X but should work across the board.

Comment: When available, you can use the Alt key for Meta. So Alt-A toggles set-mark and release-mark

Comment: Works great, thank you! Can someone tell me the reason why "M" stands for escape?

Comment: Good question, I had to do some searching but found it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_key

Comment: Also, I tried alt but it didn't work on my console. Could be my emulation though, I have some custom settings because of the servers I connect to.